# Results are not published in azure pipeline after test execution completes

Tags: azure, selenium, azure-devops, nunit, azure-automation

Triggering Test Automation after creating pipeline release in Azure cloud. After test execution gets completed, not able to see test results back in azure. Seeing error log as TestResult.xml does not matches 'NUnit' test results format.

Technical Stack : C#, NUnit, Selenium , Azure

```
2019-11-11T07:48:53.6045046Z ##[section]Starting: UI: Publish Test Results **\*.xml
2019-11-11T07:48:53.6045046Z ==============================================================================
2019-11-11T07:48:53.6045046Z Task         : Publish Test Results
2019-11-11T07:48:53.6045046Z Description  : Publish test results to Azure Pipelines
2019-11-11T07:48:53.6045046Z Version      : 2.158.0
2019-11-11T07:48:53.6045046Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-11-11T07:48:53.6045046Z Help         : [Learn more about this task](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613742)
2019-11-11T07:48:53.6045046Z ==============================================================================
2019-11-11T07:48:54.3203486Z [command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" --version
2019-11-11T07:48:54.4922262Z 2.2.108
2019-11-11T07:48:54.4922262Z [command]C:\Vsts\Agent-1\_work\_tasks\PublishTestResults_0b0f01ed-7dde-43ff-9cbb-e48954daf9b1\2.158.0\modules\TestResultsPublisher.exe @C:\Vsts\Agent-1\_work\_temp\b5ad22b0-0457-11ea-9e79-9db0871d9ecd.txt
2019-11-11T07:49:36.6438230Z ##[warning]Invalid results file. Make sure the result format of the file 'C:\TestAutomation\QA\TestResult.xml' matches 'NUnit' test results format.
2019-11-11T07:49:36.6438230Z ##[section]Async Command Start: Publish test results
2019-11-11T07:49:36.6438230Z ##[section]Async Command End: Publish test results
2019-11-11T07:49:36.6438230Z ##[section]Finishing: UI: Publish Test Results **\*.xml
```

Comment: Can you share the xml content?

Comment: Also are you using VSTest as test runner in azure?

Comment: @JAbdul Did you get a chance to try out using Nunit-v2-result-writer? Please let me know how did it go?

Answer (score 0):

Donot know if you are using nunit@3. It is a known issue for nunit@3. VSTS does not support NUnit3 format currently.

You can go vote it up and keep track on it [here](https://github.com/nunit/dotnet-test-nunit/issues/75).

Currently you can try the workaround to using [Nunit-v2-reslut-writer](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-v2-result-writer), or add a powershell task to run the transform scripts as suggested in above open issue.